# How to permanently append user input to a variable in PHP from a SQL table

Tags: php, sql, append

Any help would really be appreciated. What I'm trying to is have users add songs to the playlist of the SCM player that I have in my forum. So this is the control flow I've got right now. The first part is getting the user input.

```
<form action="/phpbbauto/scmplayersend.php" method="post">
    <?php
        echo '<input class="searchbox" type="text" name="liensc" placeholder="Add to Playlist..." /><input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="&#xf067" onclick=$onc title="Search" />';
    ?>
</form>
```

That works perfectly. Now here's the php file it send the data to.

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
define('DB_USER', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'xxxxxxxxxx');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$link){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if(!db_selected){
    die('Can\'t find ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

 //Connection Established//Data Hander Below This Line//

$valone = $_POST['liensc']; //Data from form stored//

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (liensc) VALUES ('$valone')";

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: '. mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();

?>
```

That works fine as well. Now here's the two problems I'm having.

```
<!-- Song Player http://playlist.me -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://playlist.me/w/script.js" 
data-config="{
    'skin':'skins/black/skin.css',
    'volume':10,
    'autoplay':true,
    'shuffle':true,
    'repeat':1,
    'placement':'top',
    'showplaylist':false,
    'playlist':[
        <?php  
define('DB_NAME', 'xxxxxxxx');
define('DB_USER', 'xxxxxxxxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'xxxxxxxxx');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$link){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if(!db_selected){
    die('Can\'t find ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

        $appe = "SELECT liensc FROM demo";
        $tshell = ",{'title':'$appe','url':'$appe'}";
        $stringco = "{'title':'Eddy Christiani and Frans Poptie - Rythm For You','url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3sOnASmR24'},"; 

        echo $stringco . $tshell; 

        $sql = "DELETE FROM demo WHERE ID=1";

        if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: '. mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();?>
    ]}" >
</script>
<noscript><a href="http://playlist.me/songs/">player playlist</a></noscript>
<!-- playlist.me script end -->
```

First problem: Yes , it actually appends. Problem is doesn't append the value inside the column, only the actual SQL command. How can I fix this?

Second problem: It appends, but I am not sure it will be permanent when the next value get appended.

Any help will be appreciated. I've worked on this all day and because I'm a beginner I've just driven myself into a wall. I think I'm close, but I also could be super far away from the actual answer.

Thank you.

Comment: As you are a beginner, now's the time to drop the outdated coding styles you are using.  Stop using php 4.*   and learn a little about `mysqli_` connections.  And then `PDO`.  Really learn to upgrade your code.  Seriously.  It's not that hard.

Comment: `$appe = "SELECT liensc FROM demo";` you are literally printing the SQL query instead of executing it... I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: What is stored in `liensc`? Is it the title or the url to the song? If it's either one, what's the name of the other column? You need one column for title and another for the url.

Comment: @MarcosDimitrio I'm going to eventually figure out a way to grab the youtube titles and input that for the name, but right now I'm just focused on getting the URL to be added to the play list, and I figured the easiest way to complete that step was to double the URL as the title.

Comment: @Havenard The question is how do I get the output of the SQL column I'm selecting to be equal to the $appe variable as a string, so that can plug into the $tshell variable in the format required by the player. Then, I want the correctly formatted $tshell var to be appended in front of the last song in the playlist. The reasoning behind deleting the SQL value after it gets appended is so that it doesn't keep getting copied everything someone opens the page. In saying that, I don't think I have it set up correctly to append the formatted variable and remember it the next time the script is run.

Comment: @nomistic Is it really pointless trying to do it this way? If so I can try to rewrite everything using mySQLi, but I guess it would just be nice to figure out how to do it in the way I've been doing it... and then update the code, haha.

Comment: you could do it this way as an "exercise" but I generally think it's better to learn good habits.  Your current code is highly vulnerable to SQL injection.  I recommend following something closer to the answer you were given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things I noticed on your code:

- The most important thing here is to use PDO and its API, as it will help you to prevent [SQL injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) on your site.
- As noted by @Havenard in the comments, you're printing your SQL query instead of executing and getting the results.
- It appears that your playlist.me plugin expects the title and url of the song, but your form only asks for one of those.
- To get the correct output for your plugin, you need to get the rows from your database and print them with `json_encode()`, which will output something like:

```
[{'title':'whatever song','url':'http://theaddress'},{'title':...
```

---

I rewrote your code with these suggestions in mind:

**add songs form**

```
<form action="scmplayersend.php" method="post">
    <input class="searchbox" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title of song" />
    <input class="searchbox" type="text" name="url" placeholder="Url" />
    <input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="&#xf067" title="Search" />
</form>
```

**scmplayersend.php**

```
<?php
if (count($_POST)>0) {
    $server = "myServer"; $database = "DbName"; $username = "myself"; $password = "secret";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $url = $_POST['url'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO demo (title, url) VALUES (:title, :url)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(":title", $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindValue(":url", $url, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $success = $statement->execute();

    if (!$success) {
        exit("<pre>\nPDO error: " . $statement->errorInfo()[2] . "</pre>");
    }

    exit('Song added successfully. <a href="' . $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] . '">Go back</a>');
}
?>
```

**player.php**

```
<!-- Song Player http://playlist.me -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://playlist.me/w/script.js" 
data-config='{
    "skin":"skins/black/skin.css",
    "volume":10,
    "autoplay":true,
    "shuffle":true,
    "repeat":1,
    "placement":"top",
    "showplaylist":false,
    "playlist":<?php  

$server = "myServer"; $database = "DbName"; $username = "myself"; $password = "secret";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

$sql = "SELECT title, url FROM demo";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($result);
?>'>
</script>
<noscript><a href="http://playlist.me/songs/">player playlist</a></noscript>
<!-- playlist.me script end -->
```

Comment: Finally got this to work. In the last part of it though, I had to change all the single quotation marks to double quotation marks and make the playlist config value equal to the PHP code directly. I tried using global variables like 'window' but nothing else worked. Works perfect now!

Comment: That's great to hear. For future reference, I edited the answer based on your comments to reflect the code that worked for you.